# Proving complex differentiability of a piecewise function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose we have
>
> $$ f(z) = \begin{cases} z^2 + (z-1)(z^2-1)\operatorname{Log} (z^2 - 1) , & z \neq
>  \pm 1 \\ 1, & z = \pm 1 \end{cases} $$
>
> We need to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $z=1$ and not
>   differentiable at $z=-1$.

If we try to use the definition, then

$$ f'(1) = \lim_{ z \to 1 } \dfrac{ f(z) - f(1) }{z-1} = \lim_{z \to 1} \dfrac{ (z^2-1)z\operatorname{Log}(z^2-1) }{z-1} = \lim_{z \to 1 } (z+1)z \operatorname{Log}(z^2-1)$$

But isnt this limit a non finite value and so implying the non differentiability at $z=1$? What is wrong here?

Comment: You have implicitly used $$1+ (z-1)\log(z^2-1) = z\log(z^2-1)$$ when simplifying $f(z)-f(1)$.  This is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with your algebra. You have 
$$
\frac{f(z)-f(1)}{z-1}=\frac{z^2-1+(z-1)(z^2-1)\log(z^2-1)}{z-1}=z+1+(z^2-1)\log(z^2-1).
$$
You use that $z\log z$ goes to zero at $z=0$, and so the limit exists. When $z\to-1$, now
$$
\frac{f(z)-f(1)}{z+1}=\frac{z^2-1+(z-1)(z^2-1)\log(z^2-1)}{z-1}=z-1+(z-1)^2\log(z^2-1),
$$
and term has no limit, as $z-1$ does not go zero and so the log blows up.

**Edit:** here is how to see that $z\log z\to0$, no matter what branch of log you choose. Write $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then $z\to0$ means $r\to0$. You have 
$$
|z\log z|=|re^{i\theta}\,(\theta+2k\pi+\log r)|\leq 2r(k+1)\pi+r\log r,
$$
which goes to zero when $r\to0$.

Comment: so f'(1) = 2 then. Thanks! Is there another way to solve this problem? Im having difficulties to see zlogz approaching zero as z tends to zero. The variables are complex. I know the result is true for reals, but how much stuff from reals can we assume with complex numbers?

Comment: It's very easy. I have included an edit for that.