# How do I show that if $(a_n)$ is a sequence of nonnegative numbers converging to $L$, then $L \ge 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $a_n \geq 0 $ for all $n$ and
>   $\lim a_n = L $. Prove very carefully that $L \geq 0$

This exercise I am trying to solve. Here is my ${\bf attempt:}$

Since $(a_n)$ converges to $L$, then with $\epsilon = |L| > 0$ we can obtain an $N$ so that for all $n > N$ one has

$$  a_n - L < |L| $$

and thus $0 \leq a_n < L + |L| $. If $L<0$, then $L+|L|=0$ and we obtain $0<0$ which is certainly not true! therefore $L \geq 0$ and we are done.

Is this a correct proof? Any criticism would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You merely forgot a "Assume $L<0$"

Comment: As currently written, $L=0$ breaks it.  You could simply assume $L\neq 0$ (or $L<0$) in the first line to fix it, so this isn't a big problem by any means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Here is how I would have done it. Suppose $L<0$. Since $a_n\to L$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $|a_n-L|<|L|/2$. Then
$$
a_n<L+|L|/2<0,
$$
contradicting $a_n\geq0$. Thus $L\geq0$.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Can you help me with this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646048/proving-complex-differentiability-of-a-piecewise-function

Comment: Thanks profesor!

Answer (score 2):

Here I provide an alternative way to solve it just for the sake of curiosity.

**Lemma**

If $a_{n}\geq b_{n}$ and $(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}\to a$ and $(b_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}\to b$, then $a\geq b$.

**Proof**

According to the definition of limits for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there are $N_{1}\geq m$ and $N_{2}\geq m$ such that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
n\geq N_{1}\\\\
n\geq N_{2}
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
|a_{n} - a| < \varepsilon\\\\
|b_{n} - b| < \varepsilon
\end{cases} & \Longrightarrow b - \varepsilon < b_{n} \leq a_{n} < a +\varepsilon\\\\
& \Longrightarrow a - b + 2\varepsilon > 0
\end{align*}

If we assume that $a < b$ and choose $\displaystyle\varepsilon = \frac{b-a}{2}$, then we can take $N = \max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$ such that
\begin{align*}
a - b + b - a = 0 > 0
\end{align*}
which is impossible. Therefore $a \geq b$.

**Solution**

At your case, $(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to $L$, $b_{n} = 0$ is the null sequence and $a_{n} \geq b_{n}$.

Hopefully it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should add "We assume $L < 0$ and aim for a contradiction". Then your proof is complete.

Here is an alternative proof:

If $L < 0$, there is $m$ such that $a_m < 0$ (choose $\epsilon = -L/2$ in the definition of limit), impossible by our assumption.